# How to retrieve data from json object in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to retrieve Value i.e., `80000` where Name is "Camera" from the Product's JSON using java. Can anyone please help me out ?

```
{
   "Products":{  
      "Product":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Tv",
            "Value":50000
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Camera",
            "Value":80000
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Phone",
            "Value":15000
         },
         
      ]
   }
}
```

## Mycode:

```
JSONObject arrayOfProducts = jsonObj.optJSONObject("Products");
        JSONArray products = arrayOfProducts.getJSONArray("Product");
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objects = products.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator key = objects.keys();
            while (key.hasNext()) {
                String k = key.next().toString();
                if(k.equals("Name")) {
                    if(objects.getString(k).equals("Camera")) {
                System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", value : " + objects.getString(k));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Your code look normal. But your JSON is not good. Strange quotes and JSON object must begin with "{" and end with "}". How do you create jsonObj? What error do you see?
P.S. Your can take "Name" like this: objects.getString("Name") and check "Name" existing (if you need) like this: objects.has("Name")

Comment: This is a part of json. jsonObj contains entire json through which I'm trying to parse the json. Edited quotes

Comment: Can you please edit the above code to retrieve the value of Camera i.e., 80000 ?

Comment: replace System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", value : " + objects.getString(k)); on System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", name : " + objects.getString(k) + ", value : " + objects.getInt("Value"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value in a key-value pair in a JSON you need to use the following syntax:

- `[JSONObject].get[data_type]([key_name])`.

  In the above given syntax, replace the `[JSONObject]` with the
  variable of type `JSONObject` representing the JSON. In your case,
  it is `objects`.

  replace `[data_type]` with the data type of the value at that particular key. In the 
  current case, value for the key `"Value"` is `80000` is an `Integer`.. Hence it 
  should be `getInt`.

  Replace `[key_name]` with the key whose value you need to retrieve, which in your 
  case is `"Value"`.

Hence the code snippet you need to use to get the value 80000 which with the "Camera" part is: `objects.getInt("Value")`.

Here is your overall updated code:

```
    JSONObject arrayOfProducts = jsonObj.optJSONObject("Products");
    JSONArray products = arrayOfProducts.getJSONArray("Product");
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject objects = products.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator key = objects.keys();
        while (key.hasNext()) {
            String k = key.next().toString();
            if(k.equals("Name")) {
                if(objects.getString(k).equals("Camera")) {
            System.out.println("\nKey : " + k + "\nName : " + objects.getString(k) + ", \nValue : " + objects.getInt("Value"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong.

- Don't use left/right quotes. Instead use quotes without a direction.

**Correct:** `"Products"`
**Wrong:** `“Products”`

- Each JSON object should be enclosed in `{}`. Enclose your whole JSON file content within `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to choose complex solution to parse JSON like that?

You should use define some  entities and then use library for reading JSON value (Ex: "ObjectMapper" of jackson) to parser it to Object.

You can leave all complex parts for them, after that you just working on java object.